# .NET Core 2.0 Change Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a `HomeController` and `CourseController`. `HomeController` route should look be `www.domain.com/home/{action}`, and `CourseController` route should be `course.domain.com`.

Here is what I did to add `www` before the domain

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Host != new HostString("www.domain.com"))
    {
        var withDomain = context.Request.Scheme + "://www.domain.com" + context.Request.Path;

        context.Response.Redirect(withDomain);
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

I am wondering how do I change the `CourseController` path while retaining the `HomeController` path?

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't `course.domain.com` work better as a separate project? Why `domain.com/course` is bad?

Comment: You probably need to use a reverse proxy for this. I don’t think you can host the app on two domains while also separating them properly within your project (at least not without a lot of effort on your behalf).